# Joining tables through Python MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am a recent user of python and MySQLdb and I want to know why I am unable to recieve a result by running a sql query in python. The query I ran was: "SELECT dividend FROM Dividends, Avatar_recs WHERE Dividends.entityID=Avatar_recs.entityID , Avatar_recs.avatarID='1'"

I recieve an error message saying there is something wrong with my query when I know if I done this query directly on the database it would work.

Who knows where I am going wrong????

Answer (score 2):

You have this:

```
SELECT dividend
    FROM Dividends, Avatar_recs
    WHERE
        Dividends.entityID=Avatar_recs.entityID , Avatar_recs.avatarID='1'
```

I would try this - your comma syntax in the where clause doesn't look familiar:

```
SELECT dividend
    FROM Dividends, Avatar_recs
    WHERE
        Dividends.entityID=Avatar_recs.entityID AND Avatar_recs.avatarID='1'
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to have worked. I now realise my mistake where I should have wrote AND instead. Once again many thanks